# Help with intuition regarding an integration problem

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I found this question from a Korean SAT exam:

> The sequence $a_n$, is defined as $a_1=-1, a_n=2-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}},
> > n≥2$
>
> $f(x)$ is defined at $[-1,2), n\in\mathbb{N}$,
>
> $f(x)=\sin2^n\pi x$ and $a_n≤x≤a_{n+1}$
>
> The number of $t$ that satisfy the equation
> $\int_{\alpha}^{t}f(x)dx=0$ is $103$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R},
> > -1<\alpha<0$ and $0<t<2$.
>
> Hence find the value of $\log_2(1-\cos2\pi \alpha)$.

To solve this, one solution stated that I should define the integral from alpha to $0$ (the integral is negative for some reason) as some constant $k$ and the function of the integral from $0$ to $t$ as a function with respect to $t$, $h(t)$. And that the number of t that satisfies the equation can be found as the number of intersections of $y=k$ and $y=h(t)$.

The rest of the solution is intuitive, but I can't really fully understand why the number of intersections satisfies the equation. It seems correct but I can't grasp it fully.